# Why does an LLVM pass based on FunctionPass not get triggered for certain functions?

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am learning to write LLVM pass by trying to reproduce [hello world](http://releases.llvm.org/3.8.0/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#quick-start-writing-hello-world) example. The pass `hello.cpp` looks like:

```
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"

using namespace llvm;

namespace {
  struct Hello : public FunctionPass {
    static char ID;
    Hello() : FunctionPass(ID) {}

    bool runOnFunction(Function &F) override {
      errs() << "Hello: ";
      errs().write_escaped(F.getName()) << '\n';
      return false;
    }
  };
}

char Hello::ID = 0;9
static RegisterPass<Hello> X("hello", "Hello World Pass", false, false);
```

The sample program `world.c` looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The program is compiled using the following command line: `clang world.c -c -emit-llvm -O3 -o world.bc`

The bitcode produced by `llvm-dis` looks like:

```
; ModuleID = 'src/hello.bc'
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"

@str = private unnamed_addr constant [12 x i8] c"Hello World\00"

; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define i32 @main() #0 {
  %puts = tail call i32 @puts(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([12 x i8], [12 x i8]* @str, i64 0, i64 0))
  ret i32 0
}

; Function Attrs: nounwind
declare i32 @puts(i8* nocapture) #1

attributes #0 = { nounwind uwtable "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="false" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }
attributes #1 = { nounwind }

!llvm.ident = !{!0}

!0 = !{!"clang version 3.8.0 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)"}
```

When I run the pass on the bitcode: `opt -load hello/libhello.so -hello src/world.bc > /dev/null`, the output is:

```
Hello: main
```

However, the [tutorial](http://releases.llvm.org/3.8.0/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#running-a-pass-with-opt) claims that the output should have been:

```
Hello: __main
Hello: puts
Hello: main
```

Why does my pass not get triggered for the first two functions?

Answer (score 2):

I've read that tutorial, but I've never seen any symbols named `__main`.
I've always assumed that it used to be some sort of relic from older versions of LLVM/Clang, inserted and used as an entry point to an executable.

There is no definition or declaration of any function with such name in your bitcode file anyhow.

Moreover, I think that the `puts` function being output is an error in the tutorial. A function pass is supposed to perform analyses/transformations on the *body* of a function. The reference to `puts` is simply a declaration because it is an external symbol that is defined in the `C` standard library and it will be resolved during linking. It has no body defined in the bitcode file.

If you require to go through function declarations as well, then you need to create a `Module` pass and use the `isDeclaration()` [function](http://apt.llvm.org) call to distinguish them.

Comment: What you say makes perfect sense. However, I wonder how they came up with the output listed above. I mean I'm surprised if the official documentation is so bogus.

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock I think it's just neglect. The example is aimed more towards getting the build and run machinery going; for all the rest there's the doxygen generated doc and the source itself. The doc is under the svn repo, so I guess anyone can amend it.